# PHP not remembering the IP address of a domain name

Tags: php, dns, resolve

System:

- CentOS 7
- PHP-FPM 7.1

Issue:

- PHP resolves local domain name only if it is set for the DHCP server as static  address
- The server won't have any connection in the future to the DHCP server, thus it is unable to resolve the IP address of the domain name.

Tried:

- Tried to test if it remembers the ip address if I remove it from the DHCP server (but it still has direct connection to the other server)
- `gethostbyname("mylocal.example.com");` comes back with the domain name itself as result
- The domain name is added to the `/etc/hosts` file. Restarted network since then a few times.

Question:

- How can I burn in PHP to lookup a specific domain name on an specific IP address?

Answer (score 0):

The same domain name is returned by gethostbyname function only when its not able to resolve that host.

To resolve a non-existent domain name from host file add a trailing dot to the domain name. 
E.g.  `gethostbyname(“mydomain.com.”);`

Comment: Yes, the question is: How can I let the PHP application know that this domain is located here? Isn't it enough if I just add it to the hosts file? Apparently not.